# Spring Boot not starting HTTP listener

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When I start the Spring Boot application jar I get nothing about service listening on HTTP port or any error. Posting a bit obscured pom.xml and start-up screencap:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>**.***.****</groupId>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.1</logback.version>
        <libotp.version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</libotp.version>
        <apachecommons3.version>3.0.1</apachecommons3.version>
        <stormpath.version>1.0.RC5.1</stormpath.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>**.***.****</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kamranzafar</groupId>
            <artifactId>libotp</artifactId>
            <version>${libotp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${apachecommons3.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Application class is a standard class generated from start.spring.io

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image: Just this nothing else]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a missconfiguration in your logging.
Smth. like multiple appenders or so.

Just try to remove all the `slf4j` and `logback` dependencies. 
Those will be added automatically for you.

The reason you 'see' the banner is because it gets printed via std out.
See [this code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L523-L547) from the `SpringApplication.java`

Answer (score 2):

I notice that you are referencing a Stormpath version in the properties section.

Here's the minimal pom you'd need to include Spring Boot + Spring Security + Thymeleaf + Stormpath (Note: This includes all the other relevant Spring Boot starters):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>**.***.****</groupId>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.RC5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The `repackage` goal on the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` gives you the nice uber jar.

Full Disclosure: I work for Stormpath.

Comment: Thanks, will it cover my dependencies without conflict since I'm not using either spring security or thymeleaf